# How to fix electron sqlite3 rebuild error ( Syntax error) on windows 10

Tags: node.js, sqlite, electron, rebuild

So I ran `npm install --global windows-build-tools` thing as an administrator and it said that I have successfully installed python 2.7.

But then when I tried `electron-rebuild -f -w sqlite3` after `npm i sqlite3` it gives me this error.

> × Rebuild Failed
>
> An unhandled error occurred inside electron-rebuild
>
> gyp ERR! configure error
>
> gyp ERR! stack Error: Command failed:
>   C:\Users\newub\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\python.EXE -c
>   import sys; print "%s.%s.%s" % sys.version_info[:3];
>
> gyp ERR! stack   File "", line 1
>
> gyp ERR! stack     import sys; print "%s.%s.%s" %
>   sys.version_info[:3];
>
> gyp ERR! stack                                ^
>
> gyp ERR! stack SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Answer (score 1):

According to the message you are using `Python 3.7` but those code need `Python 2.7` to run.

> You can identify which Python version `node-gyp` should use in one of the following ways:
>
> 2. If `node-gyp` is called by way of `npm`, *and* you have multiple versions of Python installed, then you can set `npm`'s 'python' config
>      key to the appropriate value:
>
> ```
> $ npm config set python /path/to/executable/python
> ```
>
> 3. If the `PYTHON` environment variable is set to the path of a Python executable, then that version will be used, if it is a compatible
>      version.
> 4. If the `NODE_GYP_FORCE_PYTHON` environment variable is set to the path of a Python executable, it will be used instead of any of the
>      other configured or builtin Python search paths. If it's not a
>      compatible version, no further searching will be done.

You can use `set` command in cmd dispaly environment variable.

PS: Using `node-gyp` in Windows needs `Visual C++ build tools`, `Python 2.7` (`v3.x.x` is not supported) and some config. You can

> Install all the required tools and configurations using Microsoft's
>   windows-build-tools by running `npm install -g windows-build-tools` from
>   an elevated PowerShell (run as Administrator).

See:

> set python version: [nodejs/node-gyp: Node.js native addon build
>   tool](https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp#configuring-python-dependency)
>
> Environment setup and configuration: [nodejs-guidelines/windows-environment.md at master ·
>   microsoft/nodejs-guidelines](https://github.com/Microsoft/nodejs-guidelines/blob/master/windows-environment.md#environment-setup-and-configuration)

Answer (score 0):

It shows node-gyp is using python 3 in your system.

But node-gyp needs python 2.

You can add python 2 Path in your $Path environment variable before python 3 Path.

type `which python` in cmd make sure it's python 2.